# How to paper print a dataframe?

Tags: python, winapi, printing, pywin32, printers

All online search relates printing a df in console. Does python have the capability to print a df directly (without saving it as a file in windows) ?

To clarify - It should not be saved as a pdf/excel/any other file. Can we print (to paper) the dataframe directly?

As far as my exploration, I think we cannot print anything (string / graph / etc) directly from Python. We might always have to do it via a file (doc/excel/pdf). Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Pandas DataFrame into a PDF file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155776/export-pandas-dataframe-into-a-pdf-file-using-python)

Comment: `Can we print (to paper) the dataframe directly?` What does it mean? Can I think you need to send print job to printer and it can print directly without saving it as a file?

Comment: Exactly. That is what I am wondering if its possible.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `win32print` module.

Please read the following [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/print-spooler) first:

> Applications that print create a printer device context (DC). When an
> application creates a printer DC, the spooler performs necessary tasks
> such as determining the location of the required printer driver and
> then loading that driver. The print spooler also determines the data
> type used to record the print job.
>
> The print spooler supports the following data types:
>
> - Enhanced metafile (EMF).
> - ASCII text.
> - Raw data, which includes printer data types such as PostScript, PCL,    and custom data types.
>
> Custom data types can be added to the spooler by installing
> additional printer
> drivers and print processors. A print job is a document stored
> internally and encoded by using one of the supported data types, and a
> print job may contain one or more pages of output.
>
> **The spooler deletes these files when the job has successfully printed.**

It is indeed possible to print jobs directly without saving them as files, because the spooler will delete these files directly after printing.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14615664/11128312

Comment: @Harsh Khad Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. But looks like printing directly is way more complicated than printing via a file (with formats, layouts, etc. all easily handled).